# Horizontal scrollbar by mouse-wheel script, can't get it to work

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, mousewheel

I found this one script and tried to change it to fit my needs, but for some reason, it just doesn't work on my example, why is that?
The scroll works fine but won't react to mousewheel...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.row-horizon').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/902tjbzz/66/)**

Answer (score 1):

It works if you remove the "< /script>" at the end of the javascript window in JsFiddle. If you do not remove it JsFiddle treats it like an syntax error and the jQuery will not be performed it seems.